# Error there is no package called RevoUtilsMath with R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am running R 3.4.3 and 3.5.1 (non-Microsoft version) and RStudio version 1.1.456.  I am trying to knit some code into RMarkdown.  However, I get the following error:

`Error in library(p, character.only = TRUE) : there is no package called 'RevoUtilsMath'Calls: <Anonymous> ... suppressPackageStartupMessages -> withCallingHandlers -> library
Execution halted`

The package `RevoUtilsMath` is part of the MKL install with Microsoft R.  I cannot install it as a supplemental package with 'regular R'.  The script itself runs fine, it just does not work in R Markdown.

The following libraries are loaded:

````
```{r loadLibraries, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(RODBC)
library(dplyr)
library(markovchain)
library(DT)
library(reshape2)
library(knitr)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(plotly)```
````

The missing package error happens when executing the code below in Markdown.  It is called using this code.

````
```{r histogram1, echo=FALSE, cache=TRUE}```
````

The histogram1 code is below (very standard ggplot).

```
 g <- ggplot(dataClean, aes(x = IncSnapshotDay, fill = Represent)) + 
  geom_histogram(bins=70, alpha = .8) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = colors) + 
  scale_x_continuous(labels = comma, limits = c(0,40000)) + 
  facet_wrap(~SnapshotDay) + 
  ylim(0,4000)  +
  theme_bryan()
  g
```

I thought that maybe one of these packages has a dependency, so I ran the following to find out.

```
library(tools)
> dependsOnPkgs('RevoUtilsMath')
```

It returns `character(0)` which indicates that none of the packages depend on it.  I did a test of the function on ggplot2, and it works

```
dependsOnPkgs('ggplot2')
[1] "dendextend" "GGally"     "ggthemes"   "plotly"     "viridis"    "caret"      "crosstalk" 
[8] "DT"
```

So why does R Markdown/knitr generate this error since the code itself runs fine outside of Markdown, and how do I fix this?

Comment: I don't think there is sufficient information to solve this. Can you provide a dull, minimal working example R Markdown document?

Answer (score 6):

I think you are experiencing a problem similar to one I just had though, without more detail, it is hard for me to know.

In my case, the problem was caused by knitr caching the list of packages used by a previous author (using Microsoft R). The immediate solution was to simply clear the knitr cache (via the "Knit" drop down menu in RStudio) before attempting to knit the code.

I still don't really understand why this is happening or how to avoid it in future situations, but this at least provides a way to create the document even in the face of this behavior.

Comment: That sounds like the issue.  Thanks.

Comment: I recently updated r and used it as an opportunity to reload all packages from scratch.  I got then this error message on a document that used to knit fine.  While the suggestion above to clear the cache was insufficient, it did provide the missing clue.  Removing cache = T from the knitr options worked.

Comment: I did not find the "Knit" drop down menu, but deleting the folder `cache` by hand worked.